# replacement for [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:player]; - does it explain why I can’t hear audio?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avaudiosession

I’m updating an earlier app that used `setDelegate` to configure `AVAudioSession` to play audio. I’m at the stage of hooking up the new UI to drive the audio but I get no sound. When I updated the app a year ago, Xcode notified that `setDelegate: was deprecated` but I was able to get audio by commenting out

```
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:player];
```

and replacing it with

```
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
```

EDIT: My session uses `setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` because I need to use `audioRouteOverride:` (*[I queried this in Feb 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18808124/2348597)*)

The code below shows how `AVAudioSession` was initialised. What puzzles me is that this is the same code that produced audio back then even though `player.delegate = self;` was specified two lines above the `setDelegate:player`statement (*see below*).

The [latest Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616556-delegate) also says to

> Use the notifications described in the Responding to Audio Session
>   Notifications ...

and invites me to download Beta software. But first it would be better to deal with a problem I might have created. My problem is likely to be a result of changes made to the UI (where buttons activate sine tones synthesised from a look up table).

Before I back track through revisions made over the past few weeks I am posting code related to my problem in case it explains why I do not hear audio. I’d be really grateful if anyone can point out something I haven’t noticed. Thanks

```
    float sampleRate = 44100.0f;

    // Initialise the audio buffer.

    player = [[AudioBufferPlayer alloc] initWithSampleRate:sampleRate channels:1 bitsPerChannel:16 packetsPerBuffer:1024];
    player.delegate = self;
    player.gain     = 0.9f;

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
    //  [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:player];

    [player start];
```

*(A full listing of the initial code is available using links [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37773533/2348597)).*

Comment: You need to set `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` category for your audio session. Also it looks like duplicate question.

Comment: John, I use     AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord (see my edit). A duplicate question might be helpful at this stage